# 32 Inch additional monitor texts get pixelated On Dell Core i7 laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell-inspiron

Could you please help me with this issue? :
I've connected a 32-inch ASUS VG328H1V 165Hz monitor with my laptop. And the texts become pixelated. I've tried the following;

1. Changing resolution
2. Changing graphics setting

Is it something because of my laptop configuration? I've added a summary on my laptop configuration:

DELL Inspiron 15 5000 Laptop
10th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-1065G7 Processor (8MB Cache, up to 3.9 GHz)
Windows 10
NVIDIA® GeForce® MX230 with 4GB GDDR5 graphics memory

Here’s a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Thank you very much for your kind reply.
Regards,
Mahruf Hussain

Comment: How are you connecting the display? HDMI or DisplayPort? Is it set to its native resolution? Is the issue visible on screenshots? If yes, please provide a screenshot. If not, please try to take a photo illustrating the issue. // I also see the display supports only 1920x1080. This is not a suitable resolution for a 32-inch computer display.

Comment: Hey,
Your consideration to troubleshoot was great.
1. HDMI
2. You can see, No issues with screenshot: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/9642035?key=f96fe4468eee7f1a0e8f200155f23a28
Finally, so you're trying to say that I must have better resulation for 32", right?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It’s natural you’d find the resolution lacking compared to your laptop. The laptop is probably also 1920×1080 but your 32-inch display is roughly double the width and height. So everything is just very large by comparison and that includes the pixels.

If you’re going to use a 32-inch display as a desktop display, with a viewing distance of less than a meter, I’d suggest 4K resolution (3840×2160). At 100% scaling things would basically be the same size they are on the laptop display, the screen can just fit much more.

Additionally, depending on your laptop’s HDMI port, you may not be able to fully utilize the 165 Hz refresh rate the display offers.

Comment: YES, I CHANGED TO 5K AND WORKING PERFECTLY, THOUGH MY LAPTOP SUPPORTING ONLY 3440 X 1440..BUT IT"S OKAY NOW! THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR UR REPLY!